# Does there exist a $\in$-decreaaing sequence of sets?

Tags: set-theory

Axiom of infinity asserts that there exists a sequence of sets $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_n\in a_{n+1}$. An example is the set $\omega$.

I'm curious whether there exist a sequence of sets $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_{n+1}\in a_n$, which is a dual of Axiom of infinity. Is the existence of such sequence consistent with **ZFC**?

Comment: This can arise if the Axiom of Foundation is not assumed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - this is ruled out by the **Axiom of Foundation** (sometimes called the axiom of regularity).

---

OK, fine, there's a sense in which it is possible - we can have a model $M$ of ZFC which has no *internal* descending sequences of sets, but does have an *external* descending sequence of sets: that is, there are $a_i\in M$ with $a_{i+1}\in a_i$, but the whole sequence $(a_0, a_1, a_2, . . . )$ won't exist inside $M$ as a set. This is a subtle point, though, connected with the **Compactness Theorem** for first-order logic. See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40821/existence-of-an-omega-nonstandard-model-of-zfc-from-compactness.

The distinction between "internal" and "external" is the same as in Skolem's Paradox - there, you have a model $M$ such that $\mathbb{R}^M$ (in fact, all of $M$!) is countable, even though ZFC proves that the reals are not countable. The point is that no bijection between $\mathbb{R}^M$ and $\omega$ exists *inside $M$*.